# Javascript - convert byte to sbyte

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, byte, bitwise-operators

How can I convert byte value (0.255) to (-128 - +127) ?
e.g. 240 -> -16

The method should be fast (thinking about bitwise operators maybe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the classic would be

```
var sbyte = (byte & 127) - ((byte & 128) ? 128 : 0);
```

Or

```
var sbyte = (byte & 127) - (byte & 128);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid ifs... (conditional operators)